# How do I clear the value of a nested List<T>?

Tags: c#, list

For example, how do I clear the value of list? `List.Clear` does not work

```
List<List<int>> list = new List<List<int>>();
```

Answer (score 4):

Just do a `foreach` statement to access each individual list. Then call `clear` on it.

```
foreach (var item in list)
    item.Clear()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear the values manually in each inner lists. You can do that with any loop, here's an example with `foreach` and `for` :

```
foreach(List<int> innerItem in list)
{
    innerItem.Clear();
}



for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    list[i].Clear();
}
```

By doing only`list.Clear()` you delete every item *and* every inner list.

Answer (score 0):

```
list.ForEach(l => l.Clear());
```

using `list.Clear()` will clear your outer list.  The above code will clear your inner lists, leaving you with a list of empty lists

Comment: why not using a normal foreach? [foreach vs ForEach](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx)

Comment: same result, just using LINQ, which I enjoy more

Comment: @Jonesy that's not LINQ, that's a method on `List<T>` (or another class, or your own extension method). It uses lambdas, but it's not part of the [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.aspx) library. I for one prefer `foreach`, not `ForEach`, for the reasons in the article Fabio linked.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, i wasn't aware